# C#.NET XmlNode missing OwnerDocument in Extension Method

Tags: c#, .net, xml, extension-methods

I'm trying to create an extension method for `XmlNodes` to add a 'foreign' `XmlNode`

```
namespace TWSTools.Xml.HelperExtensions
{
    using System.Xml;

    public static class XmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static void AppendImportedChild<XmlNode>(this XmlNode value, XmlNode incomingNode)
        {
            XmlNode importNode = value.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(value, true);
            value.AppendChild(importNode);
        }
    }
}
```

But am having difficulty. For reasons unknown, I am getting the error:

XmlNode does not contain a definition for OwnerDocument and no extension method OwnerDocument accepting a first argument of type XmlNode could be found.

With a similar complaint about AppendChild on the subsequent line.

I'm using VS2105 and .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `<XmlNode>` in the extension method declaration :

```
public static void AppendImportedChild(this XmlNode value, XmlNode incomingNode)
{
    XmlNode importNode = value.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(value, true);
    value.AppendChild(importNode);
}
```

Comment: Indeed I do not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've created the method as a generic method. A generic method has type parameters. Let's rewrite it using naming conventions:

```
public static void AppendImportedChild<T>(this T value, T incomingNode)
{
    T importNode = value.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(value, true);
    value.AppendChild(importNode);
}
```

The error message is saying that you didn't constrain T to a type that implements the OwnerDocument property.

You could do that but you don't need a type parameter at all if you are only focused on XmlNode. Generic methods are useful in extension methods that are, well, generic.

So, just write it as a non-generic method:

```
public static void AppendImportedChild(this XmlNode value, XmlNode incomingNode)
{
    XmlNode importNode = value.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(value, true);
    value.AppendChild(importNode);
}
```